# Como criar uma regra de reescrita para ler um repositório a partir de um subdiretório do site

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite

Tenho duas pastas na minha raiz:

> www/repo-sp/
>   www/repo-rj/

Meu virtual host (www.meusite.local) aponta para `www/repo-sp/`:

Ao digitar `/rio` no final do site, ele deveria apontar para `www/repo-rj/`, ou seja, `www.meusite.local/rio/`

O problema é que não posso jogar nenhuma arquivo `.htaccess` na raiz destas pastas `www/repo-rj/` e `www/repo-sp/`, porém posso jogar no `www` ou em um subdiretório do repositório de sp `/www/repo-sp/rio/`.

Outro problema é que também preciso manter a ideia de que o `/rio/` deve ser mantido quando clicar no link do menu, por exemplo  "www.meusite.local/rio/link.html" quando estiver dentro do diretório do rio.

O que já tentei e não deu certo foi, colocar a regra numa arquivo `.htaccess` dentro da pasta rio:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/repo-rj/$1
```

Comment: Conseguiu fazer funcionar?

Comment: Eu resolvi sim, mas de outra maneira. Nem precisei na verdade, criar um .htaccess para o outro repositório, fiz um link simbólico dentro do projeto de SP. dentro da pasta já tinha um .htaccess: `RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/rio/]`

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer mais ou menos assim no .htaccess na raiz da www :

```
RewriteRule ^rio/(.+) /repo-rio/$1 [NC]
```

Nessa regra ele pegará o que estiver depois da barra e direcionar completamente para o '/rio'.

Não cheguei a testar, mas pode ser uma forma ou um inicio

---

Update:

Cheguei em uma coisa interessante aqui, o .htaccess continua sendo na raiz do www:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /repo-rj/
    RewriteRule ^repo-rj/(.*)$ rio/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^rio/(.*)$ repo-rj/$1

</IfModule>
```

Sempre que acessar o '/rio/algo.html' ele vai buscar o 'algo.html' dentro da 'repo-rj'

Comment: Não funcionou não...

Comment: Como ele se comportou?

Comment: ele ta redirecionando o subdiretório para outro lugar.

Comment: Vou fazer um ambiente aqui

Comment: Dei um update na resposta!